# When does aries transaction manager close jdbc connection?

Tags: jdbc, apache-camel, xa, fuseesb, aries

I'm not completely understand how aries transaction manager works in FUSE ESB 7.1.0. I would be glad if someone can explain the following situation.

I use an jdbc XADataSource (org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource) in my bundle and here is what I see: it seems like the aries transaction manager doesn't close a jdbc connection when a message was processed in a transactional route and changes where commited to a DB. Connections leave in the idle state. But after some time they are finally closed.

This led me to big problems when I try to use connection pool: an application exhauses connection pool very fast and all opened connection leave in the busy state.

I have the next questions about the aries transaction manager:

1. When it does close jdbc connections?
2. How can I tell it to close a jdbc connection when a message is
   processed and changes were committed?